# Is there possible to save CKeditor data to database correctly?

Tags: laravel, database, ckeditor

I'm trying to save my Ckeditor textarea to database. It successfully, but when I open the database it shows the tag also.
Example :
[image]

Is there a way to figure out this problem? Thanks, hope ur days is awesome!

Comment: Yes, it will store the html and therefore we used the CKEditor. Because at the time of display we need to render the content with the proper HTML. If your need is not to store the HTML then just replace the CKEditor with the simple textarea so it will not be going to store any HTML.

Comment: I want to use CKeditor and store data in database correctly without HTML. Is it possible? How can I do?

Comment: If you really want something like rich-text, you should consider using markdown.

Comment: Just use [strip_tags](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) at the time of storing the content. It will remove your HTML tags.

Comment: Yes it will remove HTML tags, but after store it to database it will be show to other page with fully function ckeditor data text

Comment: What is the benefit of using CKeditor and not storing data with HTML?

Answer (score 0):

No it's not possible.

If you're using ckeditor, you will need to store data as html, simply because you will need those when you are displaying the data.

Although you could use [htmlentities()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) to encode the charecter, and then when you need to display the string, you may use the [html_entity_decode()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php) function